# Parallel For Loop with OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have problem to parallel for-loop code in OpenMP, result of parallel for-loop is different with a sequential for-loop. How to make this code parallel with same result as sequential code.

```
counter = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0; i<L; i++) {
    int sum_found = 0;
    for(j=0; j<M; j++) {
        int found = 0;
        for(k=0; k<N_SUBSET; k++) {
            if (i==0 && unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k] < intervals[i]) {
                s_prime[counter] = unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k];
                counter++;
                found++;
            }
            else if (i!=0 && unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k] >= intervals[i-1] && unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k] < intervals[i]) {
                s_prime[counter] = unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k];
                counter++;
                found++;
            }
            else if (i==L-1 && unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k] >= intervals[i-1]) {
                s_prime[counter] = unsorted_arr[j*N_SUBSET + k];
                counter++;
                found++;
            }
        }
        C[i][j] = found;
        sum_found += found;
    }
    n_intervals_len[i] = sum_found;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with thread-sanitizer enabled?

Comment: I just compile with GCC and OpenMP

Comment: Try to add `-fsanitize=thread`. It will tell you if and where you have a data race

Answer (score 1):

As some of the context of the above code is missing (esp. the variable declarations), it's rather hard to tell what is going wrong.  But here are some ideas:

- the loop counters j and k should be declared private, because otherwise you might have a race condition on them
- the `counter++` and `found++` statements are also races for updates from different threads on the same variable.  You would either have to use an `atomic` construct for them or use a proper OpenMP reduction to get rid of the race condition.